# why i can't use `str.isupper` in list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, methods

I want print every upper case character in sorted way

```
string = "CbcBcbaA" # type(string) => str
sort_string = sorted(string) # type(sort_string) => list
for char in string:
# type(char) => str
   if char.isupper:
      print(char)
```

This print every char instead of only upper case chars
Every item in list is `class <str>`, so why I can't use string methods?

Comment: you need to *call* `char.isupper()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're forgetting to call the function. The function itself is always truthy, i.e.

```
if char.isupper:
```

is equivalent to

```
if True:
```

You'll want

```
if char.isupper():
```

instead.

Comment: Beat me to it :') GG

Comment: Nice stuff, upvoted. I'll keep my answer for clarification, as in: the reason it's true is because the method exists. If you add that to yours i'll delete mine.

Comment: @A.Abramov That's not exactly true, though; if it didn't _exist_, you'd get an AttributeError. Also, any object can override `__nonzero__` to fake being falsy.

Comment: Fair, I removed mine.

Answer (score 1):

you are not calling the function, only putting there the member function as an object, which will evaluate to true nonetheless. you should use `char.isupper()` like this:

```
string = "CbcBcbaA" # type(string) => str
sort_string = sorted(string) # type(sort_string) => list
for char in string:
# type(char) => str
   if char.isupper():
      print(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some of the code
Here is the code

```py
string = "CbcBcbaA" 
sort_string = sorted(string) # type(sort_string) => list
for char in sort_string:
   if char.isupper():
      print(char,end='')
```

`output`
`ABC`

Comment: Your answer does not add anything to the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you,

```
string = "CbcBcbaA" # type(string) => str

# define `split` function to split your string in character-based array
def split(word): 
    return [char for char in word] 

splt = split(string)
sort_string = sorted(splt) # type(sort_string) => list
for char in sort_string:
# type(char) => str
   if char.isupper():
      print(char)
```